# Mongoose: res.json returns array with null records when "toObject" is used. Why and how can I solve this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently trying to setup an API where I can fetch an array of objects that are assigned to a userId. I have defined the following Mongoose Model:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, trim: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 6 },
  engagements: [
    { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "Engagement" },
  ],
});
```

And have setup a controller like this:

```
exports.getEngsByUid = async (req, res, next) => {
  const uid = req.params.uid;

  let uidWithEngs;
  try {
    uidWithEngs = await User.findById(uid).populate("engagements");
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError("Fetching engagements failed!", 500);
    return next(error);
  }

  if (!uidWithEngs || uidWithEngs.engagements.length === 0) {
    return next(new HttpError("Could not find engagements for this user", 500));
  }

  res.json({
    engagements: uidWithEngs.engagements.map((e) => {
      e.toObject();
    }),
  });
};
```

The problem I am currently facing, is that when I send a GET requests to my defined path, I fetch an array of 'engagements' with null values:

```
{
    "engagements": [
        null,
        null
    ]
}
```

However, if I remove the toObject method (and required .map method) and setup the res as follows:

```
 res.json({
    engagements: uidWithEngs.engagements,
  });
```

I do get my array:

```
{
    "engagements": [
        {
            "_id": "5fb47975eb319d24c098a06d",
            "title": "testTitle1",
            "client": "testClient1",
            "year": 2030,
            "owner": "5fb4795deb319d24c098a06b",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fb4698aeb319d24c098a06f",
            "title": "testTitle2",
            "client": "testclient2",
            "year": 2040,
            "owner": "5fb4795deb319d24c098a06b",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Why does the use of toObject() return an array with 2 **null** records and when I don't use the toObject() method, it returns 2 complete records? How can I solve this?

Thank you|

Comment: What should happen if a `User` document doesn't have a field named `engagements`, or if that field is set to `null`?

Answer (score 0):

change res.json(...) to basically the short hand for arrow functions and it will work.